# i need to change the width of React Select box i am using React-Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React-select you can see in the image below I need to increase the width of the middle  box to similar to the right and left side box
in the middile box, I am using the multi-value option mean the user can select multi-options, and in the right and left box width is fine  the user can select one option in the right and left box
I need to increase the middlebox width similar to the left and right side box
CSS part

```
const styles = {
    control: (data) => ({
      ...data,
      width: "80%",
      height: "2.5vw",
      alignItems: "center",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#adadad",
      borderRadius: 6,
      fontSize: "0.8vw",
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    }),
```

```
<Col lg={2}>
              <label for="alert">
                <header>select</header>
              </label>
              <Select
                options={Type}
                styles={styles}
                name="alerttype"
                onChange={handleSelect}
                placeholder="Select"
                theme={(theme) => ({
                  ...theme,
                  colors: {
                    ...theme.colors,
                    text: 'black',
                    primary25: 'white',
                    primary: '#24cebd',
                    primary50: '#f5fcfb',
                  },
                })}
              ></Select>
            </Col>
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap?

Comment: yeah for box react-select and also I am using react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to get Boostrap's Cols to do the job for you, but those can be a bit tricky. I suggest using a flex-box. Since you're using React-boostrap, it's super simple:

```
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="border p-2 m-2">Select 1</div>
      <div class="border p-2 m-2">Select 2</div>
      <div class="border p-2 m-2">Select 3</div>
    </div>
```

Put your Selects into the divs and they will be equally spaced. Note the `border p-2 m-2`. That's only to give you a visual idea of the divs when you test it out. Obviously, you will style them as you see fit.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-hamilton-tvl6p?file=/index.html

Comment: then I need to remove Row and Cols

Comment: @HimanshuRathi Leave everything inside a row, but yes replace the Cols with plain divs and put them inside `<div class="d-flex align-items-center"> ... </div>`. That's the only way to get them to space right.